# How do I call this Weather API in order to show an icon instead of showing the link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I am trying to create a weather app with the WeatherAPI and I want to display the icon for the weather type.  I am calling the correct location in the nested Json code but it is displaying a link instead of the actual picture Icon.  Please help.

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
  let long;
  let lat;
  let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector('.temperature-description');
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector('.temperature-degree');
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector('.location-timezone');
  let icon = document.querySelector('.icon');

  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;

      const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
      const api =`${proxy}http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=fa00ce5daadb4##6b41171622200607&q=${lat},${long}`;

      fetch(api)
        .then(response =>{
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          const { temp_f } = data.current;
          const { text } = data.current.condition;
          //set DOM elements from the API
          temperatureDegree.textContent = temp_f;
          temperatureDescription.textContent = text;
          locationTimezone.textContent = data.location.name;
          icon.textContent = data.current.condition.icon;

        });
    });
  }

  
});
```

Sorry about the super ugly code, I am new to this. I am using the API from WeatherAPI.com.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: If `icon` (the **.icon** element) is a `<img />` element, use `icon.src = data.current.condition.icon;` instead of `icon.textContent = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

That link is a url to the image, so it's working right. You need to take that link and put it in an image tag so that it will display the image. Like so
`<img src='ThatLinkShouldGoHere'/>`

so put that link in the source of an image tag and it should work for you.

To further expound and help you out I would set the image src dynamically after you make the call to the api. so in your HTML I would have an img tag like so
`<img src='' id='myImg'/>`
and then after your call finishes so in your `.then(data=>` part. I would do a
`document.getElementByID("myImg").src = data.current.condition.icon;`
So every time you make that call your image will dynamically change depending on what you get back.

Comment: Thank you.  So do I need to add every single image individually or can I use set it as a variable in the HTML?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your question. Hopefully that helps more